# Laravel version 5.3 removed routes.php

Tags: laravel

I am new to Laravel and trying to follow some tutorials. Apparently the old routes.php has been removed and another completely different process is in place.

What do I do when a tutorial wants me to make some changes to  /app/Http/routes.php? I even created a routes.php file in the path mentioned but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing Explains the process pretty clearly the *The Default Route Files* section

Comment: My question was very specific. I need to know exact change to the tutorials.

Answer (score 6):

There is now a routes folder. Within is the `web.php` file. This is the new routes file. You can make all your routes within `web.php` the same way you did previously in `routes.php`. More info here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing

Comment: Thanks Denis. Unfortunately web.php doesn't seem to be working the same way on the tutorials that I am trying.

Comment: @agahi If you need to install a specific version of laravel, you could use composer to do so: `composer create-project laravel/laravel=4.2.0 YourAppName` would install Laravel 4.2.0.

Comment: Actually I first started with older version downloaded from github. Later I learned how to use composer and used it. These tutorials work with older version but They don't work with new one. And simply changing web.php instead of old routes.php would't work. But I guess I have to follow you advise. Thansk.

Comment: If you are looking for good Laravel tutorials for the most recent version of the framework I recommend Laracasts. https://laracasts.com/ Some of the videos are free otheriwse it's $9 per month for all lessons.

Comment: If you are going to follow a tutorial on Laravel 5.2 or before, you should either accept that you need to make things different on Laravel 5.3 or use Laravel 5.2 (or whatever the tutorial was written for).

Comment: @NestorMataCuthbert is correct. If you want to develop using Laravel 5.3, follow the 5.3 documentation. If you're following a tutorial for a different version, then develop on that version by specifying the appropriate version number in composer.